# mysql как оптимизировать order by имея 3 join'a

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, percona

СУБД: mysql percona последней версии

Есть четыре таблицы:

news
[id] [date] [text][photo_id]

sections 
[id] [name]

news_sections
[news_id] [section_id]

photos
[id] [image]

Имеем запрос который отрабатывает за 0.3 секунды вместо средних 0.03:

```
select n.*, p.image, s.name from news_sections ns
join news n on (n.id = ns.news_id)
join sections s on (s.id = ns.id)
left join photos p on (n.main_photo_id = p.id) 
where ns.id = {id}
order by n.date desc
limit 4
```

Если убрать order by то запрос отрабатывает быстро
Explain говорит что использован filesort на последнем шаге, из-за которого и есть замедление и задержка

Была попытка переписать запрос таким образом, что-бы вместо joina к news был join к отсортированный по date desc уже на момент join'a тоесть:

```
select n.*, p.image, s.name from news_sections ns
join (select * from news order by date desc) n on (n.id = ns.news_id)
join sections s on (s.id = ns.id)
left join photos p on (n.main_photo_id = p.id) 
where ns.id = {id}
limit 4
```

Explain показал что сортировка прошла, скорость увеличилась, однако после joina новости выдаются в том же порядке что и выдавались без сортировки, тоесть порядок записей в сджойненной таблицы не влияет на общий порядок выдачи.

В инете нашел что все таки можно как-то победить это подзапросами(но мне это не помогло), после 3 дней мучений я решил обратиться к мудрейшим.

Comment: Если в конце запроса нет order by то порядок итоговой выборки не определен. Если join записи не размножают и не подавляют (если в каких то таблицах нет некоторых записей), то возьмите свой второй запрос, перенесите `limit 4` в подзапрос на news и добавьте еще один order by в конец.

Comment: не помогло вообще limit 4 перенесенный в подзапрос просто забрал последнии 4 записи и потом их не смог сджойнить

Answer (score 0):

Помогла команда:
force index(index_name)
сам по себе mysql выбирает primary key приоритетней чем любой другой индекс.
Запрос стал выглядеть следующим образом:

```
select n.*, p.image, s.name from news_sections ns
join news n on (n.id = ns.news_id)
force index (date_desc)
join sections s on (s.id = ns.id)
left join photos p on (n.main_photo_id = p.id) 
where ns.id = {id}
order by n.date desc
limit 4
```